# Server client application in javafx hanging at uncertain point in time

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

Following is the code of controller of the javafx file of a client and the main.java of the server. The program hang at different time intervals and I am not sure why or where to start.

If any one of you could help in any way, it would be highly appreciated.
******controller.java***:

```
public class Controller {
    private static Socket socket;
    @FXML
    public TextArea text_area1;
    BufferedReader br;
    BufferedWriter bw;
    Stage stage1;
    @FXML
    TextField friends_id;
    @FXML
    TextField user_text;
    @FXML
    TextField login_user_id;
    @FXML
    TextField register_user_id;
    @FXML
    PasswordField register_user_pass;
    @FXML
    PasswordField confirm_pass;
    @FXML
    PasswordField login_user_password;

    public void logTheUser(ActionEvent e) {
        if (socket == null)
            makeConnectionToServer();
        System.out.println("Log IN pressed");
        sendDataToServer("login");
        sendDataToServer(login_user_id.getText());
        sendDataToServer(login_user_password.getText());
        if (readFromServer().equals("login success")) {
            openConnectWindowForLogIn(e);
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Unidentified User");
            alert.setHeaderText("please check and reenter your username and password");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void registerTheUser(ActionEvent event) {

        Stage root = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        System.out.println("I am working");
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("finalsignup.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1, 500, 300));
            stage.show();
            System.out.println("i ran");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        root.hide();

    }

    @FXML
    public void getUpdateFromServer() {
        String s1 = "hi";
        StringBuilder main_string = new StringBuilder("*****initial Chat window box*****\n");
        sendDataToServer("chat history");
        while (!s1.equals("!!end of the data pack!!")) {
            s1 = readFromServer();
            main_string.append("\n");
            main_string.append(s1);
        }
        System.out.println("data for textArea was processed ");
        int len = main_string.length();
        main_string.delete(len - 24, len);
        text_area1.setText(main_string.toString());
        text_area1.selectPositionCaret(text_area1.getLength());
        text_area1.deselect();

    }

    public void returnToMain(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage root = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1, 500, 300));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        root.hide();

    }

    @FXML
    public void openChatWindow(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            sendDataToServer(friends_id.getText());
            String str = readFromServer();
            System.out.println(str);

            if (str.equals("success")) {
                Stage root = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                try {
                    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ChatWindow.fxml"));
                    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1, 600, 400));
                    stage.show();
                    stage.setOnCloseRequest(evt -> {
                        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                        alert.setTitle("Exit Window!");
                        alert.setHeaderText("Are you sure you want to close the application?");
                        alert.showAndWait().filter(r -> r != ButtonType.OK).ifPresent(r->evt.consume());
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    root.hide();
                }
            } else {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setTitle("Unidentified User");
                alert.setHeaderText("please check and reenter a correct username for your friend");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error while entering friends id");
        }

    }


    public void makeConnectionToServer() {
        try {
            String host = "localhost";
            int port = 5000;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            out.println("server error!");
        }
    }

    public void sendDataToServer(String s) {
        if (socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                if (bw!=null) {
                    bw.write(s + "\n");
                    System.out.println("sendToServer Inner loop");
                    bw.flush();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("write disconnected");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else
            System.out.println("not connected");
    }

    public String readFromServer() {
        try {
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String str1 = br.readLine();
            return str1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error while retrieving data from server" + e.getMessage());
        }
        String str = "errors ";
        return str;
    }


    }

    public void openConnectWindow(ActionEvent event) {
        if (socket == null)
            makeConnectionToServer();
        if ((register_user_pass.getText().equals(confirm_pass.getText())) != true) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Password mismatch");
            alert.setHeaderText("the confirmed password and the prev. entered password weren't same");
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;
        }
        sendDataToServer("register The user");
        sendDataToServer(register_user_id.getText());
        if (readFromServer().equals("already present user")) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Invalid details");
            alert.setHeaderText("The user name is already taken");
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;
        }
        sendDataToServer(register_user_pass.getText());
        Stage root = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        try {

            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("connectTo.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
            stage1 = new Stage();
            stage1.setScene(new Scene(root1, 350, 200));
            stage1.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        root.hide();
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Congratulations");
        alert.setHeaderText("you're a verified User now!");
        alert.showAndWait();

    }

    public void openConnectWindowForLogIn(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage root = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        try {

            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("connectTo.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
            stage1 = new Stage();
            stage1.setScene(new Scene(root1, 350, 200));
            stage1.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        root.hide();
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Welcome");
        alert.setHeaderText("you can now chat with your friends");
        alert.showAndWait();

    }
}
```

The main.java of the server is as follows:

```
public class Main extends Thread {
    private static Socket cSocket;
    private static Statement statement;
    private static Statement statement1;
    private static Connection conn;
    private static Connection conn1;
    public BufferedWriter bw;
    public BufferedReader br;
    private Socket socket;

    Main(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
        try {
            conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\pranav\\IdeaProjects\\tryingWithJDBC\\data.db");
            statement1 = conn1.createStatement();
            statement1.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chattable(id TEXT, chatwith TEXT, chat TEXT, date DATETIME)");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\pranav\\IdeaProjects\\tryingWithJDBC\\data.db");
TEXT, password TEXT)");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                int port = 5000;
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port 25000");
                while (true) {
                    cSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    Main main = new Main(cSocket);
                    main.start();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

    }

    public boolean checkData(String s) {
        System.out.println("checking data | " + s);
        try {
            String str = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("data | " + str + " | " + str.equals(s));
            if (str.equals(s))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error while making streams for connection!");
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean data_ispresent(String s, ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            System.out.println("in data is present with: " + s);
            ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                str.add(rs.getString(1));
            }
            if (str.contains(s)) {
                System.out.println(s + " was a match!");
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println(s + " wasn't a match!");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void getChat(String username, String friend) {
        try {
            statement1.execute("SELECT * FROM chattable ORDER BY date");
            ResultSet rs = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM chattable ORDER BY date");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String inuser = rs.getString(1);
                String infriend = rs.getString(2);
                if ((inuser.equals(username) & infriend.equals(friend)) | (inuser.equals(friend) & infriend.equals(username))) {
                    {
                        sendDataToClient(rs.getString(3));
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println("string was processed");
            sendDataToClient("!!end of the data pack!!");
            rs.close();
            statement1.execute("SELECT * FROM chattable ORDER BY date");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String getDataFromClient() {
        String str1 = "exit";
        try {
            String str = br.readLine();
            return str;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error while making streams for connection!");
        }
        return str1;
    }

    public void sendDataToClient(String s) {
        try {
            StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder(s);
            s1.append("\n");
            bw.write(s1.toString());
            bw.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error while sending data to client");
        }
    }

    public void saveChat(String username, String friend, String msg) {
        try {
            StringBuilder actual_chat = new StringBuilder();
            actual_chat.append(username);
            actual_chat.append(": ");
            actual_chat.append(msg);
            java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
            statement1.execute("INSERT INTO 'chattable' VALUES ('" + username + "','" + friend + "','" + actual_chat + "','" + date + "')");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        String user_name;
        String password;
        String friends_name;
        ResultSet id_set;
        ResultSet pass_set;

        try {

            try {

                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("inside first while");
                    if (checkData("login")) {
                        //code for login
                        System.out.println("inside the login code");
                        user_name = getDataFromClient();
                        password = getDataFromClient();
                        try {
                            id_set = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM userdata");
                            boolean bool = data_ispresent(user_name, id_set);
                            id_set.close();
                            pass_set = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT password FROM userdata");
                            boolean bool2 = data_ispresent(password, pass_set);
                            pass_set.close();
                            if (bool & bool2) {
                                System.out.println("executed this");
                                sendDataToClient("login success");
                                break;
                            } else {
                                sendDataToClient("login failed");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "in the login code itself");
                        }
                    } else {
                        user_name = getDataFromClient();
                        boolean bool3 = false;
                        try {

                            id_set = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM userdata");
                            bool3 = data_ispresent(user_name, id_set);
                            id_set.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                        System.out.println("line0 " + user_name);

                        if (bool3)
                            sendDataToClient("already present user");
                        else {
                            sendDataToClient("user Verified");
                            String pass = getDataFromClient();
                            System.out.println("line1 " + pass);
                                     try {
                                statement1.execute("INSERT INTO 'userdata' VALUES ('" + user_name + "', '" + pass + "')");
                                catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("inside the loop of connect window");
                    friends_name = getDataFromClient();
                    boolean bool3 = false;
                    try {

                        id_set = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM userdata");
                        bool3 = data_ispresent(friends_name, id_set);
                        id_set.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    if (bool3)
                        break;
                    sendDataToClient("fail");
                }
                sendDataToClient("success");

                while (true) {
                    String str1 = getDataFromClient();
                    String s2;
                    if (str1.equals("exit")) {
                        System.out.println(str1);
                        System.out.println("exiting the server");
                        break;
                    } else if (str1.equals("chat history")) {
                        System.out.println("chat history called");
                        getChat(user_name, friends_name);
                        System.out.println("chat history sent");
                    } else if (str1.equals("just chat")) {
                        s2 = getDataFromClient();
                        saveChat(user_name, friends_name, s2.substring(1));
                        System.out.println("was executed");
                        System.out.println("Message received from client is " + s2);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("invalid request by the client");
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    System.out.println("closing connection");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("error closing!");
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (socket != null)
                socket = null;
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

****The fXML files are as follow: ********
**ChatWindow.fxml****

```
<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" scaleX="2.0" scaleY="1.3" text="CHAT WINDOW" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#2336ff24" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
         <font>
            <Font size="25.0" />
         </font>
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="40.0" left="130.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <TextArea fx:id="text_area1" editable="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" scaleX="2.2" scaleY="1.2" style="-fx-background-color: green; -fx-text-fill: black; visibility: true;" text="*************Chat History*****************" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="120.0" />
         </GridPane.margin></TextArea>
      <TextField fx:id="user_text" scaleX="1.81" style="-fx-background-color:#c8c9d3; -fx-text-fill:white" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="130.0" right="130.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets />
         </opaqueInsets></TextField>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#sendToServer" scaleX="1.3" text="Send!" textFill="#079dd3" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
         </font>
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="70.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="refresh_button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getUpdateFromServer" text="refresh" textFill="#11ae33" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

***sample.fxml***

```
<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label contentDisplay="RIGHT" lineSpacing="4.0" text="User Name">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" text="Password" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <font>
            <Font size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <PasswordField fx:id="login_user_password" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <TextField fx:id="login_user_id" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
      <Button fx:id="log_in_button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#logTheUser" scaleX="1.3" text="Log In" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
         <font>
            <Font size="16.0" />
         </font>
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="5.0" top="25.0" />
         </GridPane.margin></Button>
      <Button fx:id="new_user_button" onAction="#registerTheUser" mnemonicParsing="false" scaleX="1.1" text="New User?" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="27.0" top="25.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Button>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

****connectTo.fxml***

```
<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints />
        <ColumnConstraints />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <Label scaleY="1.6" text="Chat with:" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            <font>
                <Font size="15.0" />
            </font>
            <GridPane.margin>
                <Insets left="25.0" top="30.0" />
            </GridPane.margin></Label>
        <TextField fx:id="friends_id" scaleX="1.2" scaleY="1.3" text="Enter Friends ID" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            <padding>
                <Insets left="5.0" />
            </padding>
            <GridPane.margin>
                <Insets left="25.0" top="30.0" />
            </GridPane.margin>
            <opaqueInsets>
                <Insets />
            </opaqueInsets>
        </TextField>
        <Button fx:id="connect_button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openChatWindow" scaleX="1.7" scaleY="1.15" text="CONNECT!" textFill="#25d35f" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
            <GridPane.margin>
                <Insets left="100.0" top="40.0" />
            </GridPane.margin>
            <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
            </font>
        </Button>
        <Label text="WELCOME" textFill="#506dff" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
            <GridPane.margin>
                <Insets left="69.0" />
            </GridPane.margin>
            <font>
                <Font size="23.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

Unable to upload the code for finalsignup.fxml because of the character limit constraint.

The JavaFx main just loads the sample.fxml;

It would be great if you could also suggest to me how to automatically and continually update/refresh the text area with the help of threads as I was unable to do this as well.

Comment: Do not block the JavaFX application thread with longrunning tasks!!!

Comment: @fabian Could you please elaborate I am a bit new to Java particularly JavaFX

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm ; This method is unfortunately not mentioned on the previously linked page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-